# How to pass extra data to a broadcast receiver with android remote input

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-pendingintent, remote-input

I've seen a couple of duplicates for this question so I'm sorry in advance if I've missed one but none that I've found have a solution, case in point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622460/how-to-access-extra-bundle-sent-along-with-remote-input-in-direct-reply-notifica) I'm trying to do the same thing as this though. I want to use direct reply (Messaging style) notifications but I need to add some extra data (recipientId etc) and I'm confused as to where I can add this extra data my code for the intent, pending intent, and RemoteInput looks like this

```
    String replyLabel = getString(R.string.notif_action_reply);
    intent = new Intent(this, ReplyReceiver.class);

    replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    RemoteInput remoteInput = new 
    RemoteInput.Builder(NOTIFICATION_REPLY).setLabel(replyLabel).build();
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new 
    NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp,
            this.getString(R.string.reply), replyPendingIntent)
            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
            .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
            .build();
```

now to send that extra data I have tried adding it as strings

```
intent.putExtra(Constants.MSG_RECIPIENT, message.getRecipientId());
```

and as bundles

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Constants.MSG_RECIPIENT, message.getRecipientId());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

in both the intent and as part of the RemoteInput

```
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(NOTIFICATION_REPLY)
.setLabel(replyLabel).addExtras(bundle).build();
```

and in trying to get the data back I've tried to get it from the onReceive intent as either a string or a bundle

```
intent.getExtras(); 
intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MSG_RECIPIENT);
```

but nothing seems to work for me the results are always null on the other side (data is definitely not null when sent) can somebody tell me how to add the intent data and retrieve it on the other side?

**UPDATE**

Ok it now works I'm going to add the working code for others so to send the data i'm adding it to the first intent  and calling FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT on the pending intent

```
    String replyLabel = getString(R.string.notif_action_reply);
    intent = new Intent(this, ReplyReceiver.class);
    //intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.MSG_SENDER_NAME, message.getSenderName());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.MSG_SENDER, message.getSenderId());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.MSG_RECIPIENT_NAME, 
    message.getRecipientName());
    intent.putExtra(Constants.MSG_RECIPIENT, message.getRecipientId());

    replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
    (this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    RemoteInput remoteInput = new 
    RemoteInput.Builder(NOTIFICATION_REPLY).setLabel(replyLabel).build();
    NotificationCompat.Action action = new 
    NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp,
            this.getString(R.string.reply), replyPendingIntent)
            .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
            .setAllowGeneratedReplies(true)
            .build();
```

and to receive it I'm using this in onReceive

```
 String senderId = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MSG_SENDER_NAME);
```

Comment: Try adding `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `getBroadcast()`: `replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`; Also, you didn't show where you add the "extras" to the `Intent`. You must add them BEFORE you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: thank you very much this worked for me I was putting the extras in the right place so I'm guessing it was the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT that fixed it, if you want to add this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `getBroadcast()`:

```
replyPendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also, you didn't show where you add the "extras" to the Intent. You must add them BEFORE you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.